# Call to a member function getOptions() on null

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a website that I have been working of for a few years on and off and today it broke...

After trying to access the site - (http://justhardware.co.uk/) I get the following error thrown.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on null in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\justhardware.co.uk\httpdocs\app\Mage.php on line 329

The code on line 329 is:

> ```
> 327  - public static function getBaseDir($type = 'base')
> 328  - {
> 329  -     return self::getConfig()->getOptions()->getDir($type);
> 330  - }
> ```

Please help!

Comment: revert the changes done before error...do you have the last modified files or did you install any extension?

Comment: Try to disable one by one custom modules, It seems that it  is not getting configuration object so, ->getDir($type) is fired on null so it is throwing an error.

Comment: @Magento2Learner I'm unable to get into front or backend to disable any custom modules.

Comment: @EwallTester I only have a backup from a few months back because I'm a bad person

Comment: magneto-root/app/etc/modules/ from here you can disable module by particular module .xml file

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd is the right answer to do

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I've disabled all of the modules to no avail, could it be something to do with permissions? When I tried to go the the magento connect manager i get the error: Unable to find writable var_dir

Comment: You error is not in this file, you get this function with error or wrong declaration in xml of in some file, please check if you have updated some file or installed some extension

Comment: @Prince Thanks, but its all fixed, the permissions were all messed up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

It was a permissions issue, Plesk wouldn't change the permissions for all users on the online interface.

To fix all i had to do was RDP into the server and change the permissions using IIS.

Not sure of the why's or where's of this but hope I can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

this file use

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml

```
        <?php
            /**
            * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
            * See COPYING.txt for license details.
            */

            /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
            ?>

            <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
            <meta property="og:title"
            content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName()) ?>" />
            <meta property="og:image"
            content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()) ?>" />
            <meta property="og:description"
            content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription()) ?>" />
            <meta property="og:url" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProduct()->getProductUrl()) ?>" />
            <?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()) :?>
            <meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($priceAmount) ?>"/>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('meta.currency') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```